# Update the table name in a formula based on cell reference in excel

Tags: excel

Can I change a reference to the table name in a formula based on a cell reference?

Example:

Table Name = 2021Data
Cell A1 = 2021

Update Cell A1 = 2022
Updated Table Name = 2022Data

I have an excel model that needs to be updated each year. Currently, I add in a new tab that has a table for 2021 data and populate a separate tab with my summary tables using formulas (VLOOKUP) using that table, but if I needed to include 2022 data, I would have to repeat my process and change each formula and change the table name for each one. Is it possible to just change the table name in the formula through a cell reference?

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

I tried creating a string but I cant figure out how to make the table reference dynamic.

Comment: Try ```=INDIRECT()```?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do, you might want to try looking into the [INDIRECT function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261).

`INDIRECT()` allows you to construct a cell reference as a string and then inject that into another formula.

Let's say you have a tab where each tab has data from a given year (in your case one for 2021 and one for 2022). If we assume that the data you want to reference is found in the same location on each tab, then in your formulas on the Summary tab, the formulas should be the same except for the sheet that you're referring to.

This might be a bit more clear with an example:

If you say you want to find the sum of cells A1:A50 on tabs that are labeled "2021" and "2021", the formulas might look like this:

- `=SUM('2021'!A1:A50)`
- `=SUM('2022'!A1:A50)`

Note, both of those formulas are exactly the same, but the name of the tab is different.

If you were to rewrite this with an `INDIRECT`, instead of including the *direct* reference to the cell range to the `SUM`, you would *indirectly* pass a string to the `INDIRECT` formula, which in turn evaluates that string to determine the reference for the `SUM`. That would look like this:

- `=SUM(INDIRECT("'2021'!A1:A50"))`
- `=SUM(INDIRECT("'2022'!A1:A50"))`

Taking this a step, further, because you're now passing a string to `INDIRECT`, you can now construct that string however you would like. For the purposes of your model, if your Summary tab has the years 2021 and 2022 stored in cells A1 and B1, then you could update the INDIRECT formula as follows:

- `=SUM(INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!A1:A50"))`
- `=SUM(INDIRECT("'"&B1&"'!A1:A50"))`

By constructing your Summary tab in this way, you are able to dynamically pull in the name of the tab allowing you to easily update your model each time a new year of data is added.